# How to navigate deeper inside a xamarin detailpage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, navigationbar, master-detail

I have a project with a MasterDetailPage as root page. When I navigate deeper inside the Detailpage, I have the problem, that the DetailPage navigation overrides my actionbar for the MasterPage. Can I have both in the actionbar, the burgermenuicon and the backbutton?

before navigation:
[image: before navigation]
after navigation:
[image: after navigation]

```
public partial class MasterPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MasterPage()
    {

        Master = SetMasterContentPage();
        Detail = new NavigationPage(new TaxonomyOverviewPage());
    }

    ContentPage SetMasterContentPage()
    {
        var masterPage = new ContentPage { Title = "Test"};
        masterPage.Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label{Text="Label1"},
                new Label{Text="Label2"},
                new Label{Text="Label3"}
            }
        };

        return masterPage;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved.

I used a public static MasterDetailPage and referenced it to the MainPage in App.cs. Now I can access the IsPresented property of the MasterDetailPage.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static MasterPage masterdetail;

    public App()
    {
     InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
      masterdetail = new MasterPage();
      Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
       MainPage = masterdetail;
       });
    }

}
```

Finally, I add a menuicon to the right side of the actionbar.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Menu", "menuicon.png", () => { App.masterdetail.IsPresented = true; }));
    }
```

Comment: That is fantastic.. I was having the exact same "problem".. Thank you